# Conexión Telnet con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, telnet, adonisjs

Buen día,

Estoy intentando conectarme vía telnet a un aparato relay Numato utilizando javascript con net.Socket para luego enviar comandos. Sin embargo, al intentar la conexión, rechaza el usuario y contraseña ya que, según veo en la salida, se cuelan caracteres y no logro encontrar en donde.
Como se puede ver en el código, intenté mirando la salida de distintas formas, en forma de json con la data, arrays, strings, y no encuentro el error.

La única conclusión a la que he llegado, ya que cuando pregunta "Password: ??-" ya viende con caracteres extraños, es que cuando intento escribir la contraseña esta se escribe después de los caracteres, pero no se en que parte de cuelan.

Si alguien sabe a que se debe o ha trabajado con módulos Numato le agradecería cualquier aporte.
A continuación, el código y su salida:

```
    var net = require('net');

    var client = new net.Socket();

    client.connect(23, '192.168.1.100', function() {
      console.log('Connected');
    });
    client.on('connect', function(){
      client.write('admin\n')
      client.write('admin\n')
      // client.write('admin\n' + 'admin\n')
    })

    client.on('data', function(data) {
      // console.log('rec:' + data);
      console.log(''+data)
      // var datos = []
      // datos.push(data)
      // datos.push(data.toJSON)
      // console.log(datos)
      // client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
    });

    client.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Connection closed');
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porqué escribes dos veces `client.write('admin\n')`?

Comment: Hola ricardo-dlc. Cuando conecto me pregunta usuario y contraseña, por lo que le envío primero 'admin\n' y luego espera la contraseña, la cual también es 'admin'.

Comment: Ok entiendo, intenta con `client.write('admin\r\n')` a la vez que guardas el resultado en una variable para ver si ha llegado al buffer forma correcta.